# My model on website (three js) looks so dark

Tags: modeling, texturing

I tried to put this model into the website(three js) but it turns out model is so dark. What should I do ?[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: missing image files ? Try with the default Cube and BSDF material, then with an image texture, check for errors in the Browser console.

Comment: So texture is necessary ? I can't  just use materal to panit  or BSDF?

Comment: It seemed likely you were using an Image Texture based on the context. I wanted you to check the workflow with something simple, Cube with single BSDF material. If that works then try adding an Image Texture. The thing with Painting is you MUST save the image in Blender, not just save the .blend file or it only exists in memory and is lost on exit.